# Associated types in benchmark `where` bound

Tags: benchmarking

I'm trying to constrain the value of an associated type of a trait inside a benchmark's `where` bound, like this:

```rust
#[benchmarks(where T: currency::Config<Balance = u128>)]
pub mod benchmarks {
    use super::*;

    #[benchmark]
    pub fn set_nomination_enabled() {
        #[extrinsic_call]
        _(RawOrigin::Root, true);
    }
}
```

However, this results in an error:

```
error[E0284]: type annotations needed
    |
122 | #[benchmarks(where T: currency::Config<Balance = u128>)]
    |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
    |
    = note: cannot satisfy `<T as currency::Config>::Balance == _`
```

The `type annotations needed` error does not make any sense to me, and I suspect it may be because of some cleverness by the macro.. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of requiring an exact type, you can use a trait like `From<u128>`, or better: `From<u32>`.
Keep in mind that these bounds should be as *general as possible*.
Otherwise it artificially restricts the runtimes that your pallet can be deployed in.
For example when forcing it to `u128`, it wont work anymore with runtimes that use `u64`.

The correct bound would be:

```rust
#[benchmarks(where <T as pallet_balances::Config>::Balance: From<u32>)]
```

Then you can use `.into()` to consturct it like `let balance = 10u32.into()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. But I think `where` bounds _should_ be able to constrain associated type to exact types? See e.g. the function `f` here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=66e91b43b2338aead2320a8f4c46e4a2

Comment: Ah you are right, for associated types it works. I assumed it is a generic, but is *should* be an associated type. Anyway, keeping it generic is still a good idea. I updated the answer.